# How to stop timer on killing app android

Tags: android, timer

How do I stop my timer when I close my App (Using the Return/exit button((Not home button)))?

When I close my App using the back button it's not in the task messenger, but the timer (Sending notifications on events) is still running and sending me notifications..

I thought as it is not in the tasks, and I use the return button to close the timer would also stop..
When I open the app again after closing it it does restart on it's mainactivity unlike opening it when I used the "home" button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override finish method

```
@Override
public void finish()
{
   killYourTimer();
   super.finish();
}
```

You can also override onDestroy()
like [Houcine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704513/houcine) suggested.

Comment: Just did that, seems to work thanks. Strange that a timer won't stop when you kill an app

Comment: the timer will not be killed , because it is launched in a separated thread , that's why you should stop it when your activity is finished or destroyed

Answer (score 3):

you should override the method `onDestroy()` ( the method is executed when the activity is destroyed) and stop your timer :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(timerIsRunning)
       stopTimer();
}
```